# Looking to specifically customize Ubuntu SSH banner

Tags: ssh

So the default Ubuntu SSH banner has some cool stuff, mainly that it shows the packages that can be updated and whatnot. So I want to preserve those values, while customizing the rest of it.

I've already seen that I can point `sshd_config` to the file that would contain the text. I'm just unclear what commands will produce the update text.

For the record, what I'm talking about is this:

```
0 packages can be updated.
0 updates are security updates.
```

Help would be appreciated. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 6):

This is not a banner, but a MOTD (Message of the Day). It is generated by PAM dynamically and the static part can be simply appended as noted in the `/etc/pam.d/sshd`:

```
# Print the message of the day upon successful login.
# This includes a dynamically generated part from /run/motd.dynamic
# and a static (admin-editable) part from /etc/motd.
session    optional     pam_motd.so  motd=/run/motd.dynamic
session    optional     pam_motd.so noupdate
```

The dynamic part is generated from the `/etc/update-motd.d/` to `/run/motd.dynamic` by the `pam_motd.so` module.

Comment: Haha, i knew you would come, and answer the `ssh` tagged question thats why i refrained from answering :) Kudos :) Just an addition, `/run/motd.dynamic` is generated from files under `/etc/update-motd.d/`, at start `run-parts` is run on the files, be careful about the file names.

Comment: @heemayl hehe, you are flattering me :D Thanks for the addition (that was the part I was unable to find in a minutes). I finally wanted to find out how does it work behind the scenes in Ubuntu (fortunatelly well documented) :)