# motd message doesn't update

Tags: server, 16.04, updates, ssh, motd

I recently tried to modify the **motd** on my ubuntu 16.04 server machine. i went to the files located in **/etc/update-motd.d/** and modified the **00-header** script file to test if it was going to work.

I just added something like

```
printf " Welcome, $USER"
```

and after some time the motd was actually changed.

the problem is that now, even if i removed that **printf** and added a lot of fancy text in the other scripts, the motd is not changing at all. what can I do to manually update on the motd? Is there any way i could just force it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Looking to specifically customize Ubuntu SSH banner](http://askubuntu.com/questions/833518/looking-to-specifically-customize-ubuntu-ssh-banner)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can force it via `sudo run-parts /etc/update-motd.d/`

Comment: This will not update the motd displayed while connecting to the server. This only shows what will be displayed when the update will happen.