# SSH welcome message on 17.04 shows notice about 12.04

Tags: ssh, do-release-upgrade, motd

I just did a `do-release-upgrade` going from Ubuntu 16.04 to 17.04.
However, now when I login via SSH I have the following message

```
Welcome to Ubuntu 17.04 (GNU/Linux 4.10.0-20-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
 * Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
 * Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage

Ubuntu 12.04 LTS end-of-life was April 28, 2017 -- Upgrade your Precise systems!
 $ sudo do-release-upgrade -m server

0 packages can be updated.
0 updates are security updates.
```

My question is, how can I remove the

```
Ubuntu 12.04 LTS end-of-life was April 28, 2017 -- Upgrade your Precise systems!
 $ sudo do-release-upgrade -m server
```

it wasn't there prior the release-upgrade

I checked and I am on Zesty

```
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 17.04
Release:    17.04
Codename:   zesty
```

My question is not, how can I remove this message, this I found.
My question is more, is there a reason why this appears after a release-upgrade? Is this message something generic not taking into consideration the current version of Ubuntu? Or maybe my system is not updated properly?

Comment: Have a look at this question, it's guide you to correct configuration files, just apply your changes there ;)

Comment: Not a duplicate as you can read in the end of the question. Though related. See my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> My question is more, is there a reason why this appears after a release-upgrade?

It is probably a new feature of Ubuntu 17.04 that it tells you that you should update your other 12.04 systems that are EOL today.

> Is this message something generic not taking into consideration the current version of ubuntu?

Yes. It is generic.

> Or maybe my system is not updated properly?

The system is updated properly. I see the same message.

To clarify what is going on there, digging deeper into the [parts that generate this message](https://askubuntu.com/questions/833518/looking-to-specifically-customize-ubuntu-ssh-banner/833523#833523), we can find that the message is generated by the `/etc/update-motd.d/50-motd-news` which picks the MOTD from `https://motd.ubuntu.com/`.

So this is just a generic MOTD from Ubuntu, which should inform you about the important news around the project.

To disable the message, open the mentioned file and comment out the line including the other or just remove that file.

Comment: How can I disable this message?

Comment: @Cirelli94 open the mentioned file and comment out the line including the other or just remove that file.

Comment: Please add the procedure to disable the message into your answer

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04LTS and noticed this as well.

The console startup message files are all running from `/etc/update-motd.d/` -- look at each one (you can even run each one individually) to see what they do.

For me, the file `99-esm` is the culprit. It's a poorly-written script with Ubuntu 12.04 hardwritten into it.

**Solution:** I created a `/etc/update-motd.d/disabled` directory and moved `99-esm` into it.

My only question now is if there's supposed to be a *better* 99-esm in there. Perhaps in the future, a future `linux-image` package will put it there if needed. I'm not sure, but at least the annoyance is gone.

Answer (score 0):

This is part of left over configuration files of **ubuntu-advantage-tools** The best way to clear this is by purging this package with:

```
dpkg --purge ubuntu-advantage-tools
```

If you then login an extra time as a root user, the motd will be updated and the mention of 12.04 is gone. More info on **man update-motd**